# Wordpress New Registration Form with Radio Button

Tags: wordpress

I'm a Wordpress newbie and I am stumped. I've tried to Google it for help, looking for plugins. I haven't been successful.

I'd like to create 2 choices for the user: **Member or Vendor**, and based on their selection, it sends an email when they finish upon registration.

So if I select **Member**, then it sends an email to `member@gmail.com` or if they select **vendor**,`vendor@gmail.com` will be submitted.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a registration form in which add this selection

```
//form starts
//other fields

    <input type = "radio" name = "user_role" value = "Member">Member</input>
    <input type = "radio" name = "user_role" value = "Vendor">Vendor</input>

//submit

//on submit

    if(isset($_POST['user_role'])){
       //Here check value selected from both choices
       if($_POST['user_role'] == "Member"){
          $email_id = "member@gmail.com";
       }
        else{
          $email_id = "vendor@gmail.com";
       }
       //send email
    }
```